# How do I redirect a directory keeping URL parameters?

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a site with a URL parameter as such: http://example.com/decision.php?id=1

I have now rewritten the site and have moved all .php files to a subfolder called "new".  How do I have .htaccess (or another way) redirect the first URL to 
http://example.com/new/decision.php?id=1
All while keeping any URL parameters?

Comment: What is your backend? cPanel? Are you hosting locally? I would suggest making a redirect in your server instead of actually coding it to do what you want it to do.

Comment: Hosted with Network Solutions

Comment: What control panel does Network Solutions use? The most popular is cPanel but it could be another one

Comment: They have their own control panel.

Comment: I contacted their support team and they told me it was cPanel. (It may have a custom skin or something, but if you're using their shared hosting I think it's cPanel.) - In this case, log into your panel and find "redirects" - keep "Permanent (301)", select your domain, leave the path blank and change "Redirect To" to `http://example.com/new/`, and make sure you enable wildcard redirect. Even if they don't use cPanel, the steps should be similar on whatever panel they have, and if not, contact their support team.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this redirect rule in your site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(?!new/).+ /new/$0 [L,NC,R=301,NE]
```

Query string will be automatically forwarded to new URL.